# Find the number of permutations in these words

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Finding the number of permutations in these three words, am I doing this correctly?

a) CORRECT: $\;\dfrac{7!}{2!\cdot2!} = 1260$

b) COEFFICIENT:  $\;\dfrac{11!}{2!\cdot2!\cdot2!\cdot2!} = 2494800$

c) TATTERED:  $\;\dfrac{8!}{3!\cdot2!} = 3360$

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you've done the calculations correctly, it looks all good to me.

Answer (score 4):

Each of the following are indeed correct, for finding the number of *distinct* permutations of the given words.

a) CORRECT = $\frac{7!}{2\,\cdot2!} = 1260$

b) COEFFICIENT = $\frac{11!}{2!\,\cdot2!\,\cdot2!\,\cdot2!} = 2494800$

c) TATTERED = $\frac{8!}{3!\,\cdot2!} = 3360$

---

Your problem set-ups show exactly the correct reasoning:

E.g. word = zabczcdezefgz, we count the length $n$ of the "word": $n = 13$, and if any letters are repeated, we count the number of repetitions $x_i$ for each such letter:

- $z: x_z = 4$
- $c: x_c = 2$
- $e: x_e = 2$

Then we compute $\dfrac{n!}{\prod (x_i!)} = \dfrac{13!}{4!\,2!\,2!}$.

You did exactly that, and your calculations are also correct.

Comment: Nice that you reverse engineered the problem +1

Comment: I have a friend here who is so talented +